# peer to peer voice calling in android without sip

Tags: android, streaming, voip, audio-streaming, peer

I am  developing an application which enables user to make a voice call within a LAN (WI-FI) by streaming a raw pcm audio stream.
but I am unable to play the audio track being received

here is my receiver code:

```
   private AudioTrack speaker;



    public void startReceiving() {

        Thread receiveThread = new Thread (new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(1127);
                    Log.d("VR", "Socket Created");


                    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];


                    //minimum buffer size. need to be careful. might cause problems. try setting manually if any problems faced
                    int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                    speaker = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);


                    speaker.play();
                    while(status==true) {
                        try {


                            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
                            socket.receive(packet);
                            Log.d("VR", "Packet Received");

                            //reading content from packet
                            buffer=packet.getData();
                            Log.d("VR", "Packet data read into buffer");

                            //sending data to the Audiotrack obj i.e. speaker
                            speaker.write(buffer, 0, minBufSize);
                            Log.d("VR", "Writing buffer content to speaker");

                        } catch(IOException e) {
                            Log.e("VR","IOException");
                        }
                    }
                    speaker.play();

                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    Log.e("VR", "SocketException");
                }


            }

        });
        receiveThread.start();
    }
```

and here is my sender code:

```
public void startStreaming()
{
    Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try{

                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");

                byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize];

                Log.d("VS", "Buffer created of size " + minBufSize);


                Log.d("VS", "Address retrieved");
                recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize);
                Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized");


                recorder.startRecording();


                InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.101");
                byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
                byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];


                while (status==true)
                {
                    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 1127);
                    socket.send(sendPacket);
                }

            } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.e("VS", "UnknownHostException");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("VS", "IOException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    });
    streamThread.start();
}
```

I cant use SIP , its just a plain audio streaming. 
can  any one help me with this please

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. Your receiver thread doesn't seem to play... it is always in the loop and never reaches speaker.play().
2. Your sending thread never sends any data... For example:

   ```
   recorder.read(sendData, 0, sendData.length);
   ```

Comment: Hi msj121,  I am receiving  bytes it will be displayed when i print the logs, but I seem to receive same data i mean like 2B03F5 something like that(but it is displaying same data over and over in a loop). and I did test my sender by implementing  a java  receiver and it worked. with a little lags and overlaps.

Comment: and is there any correct placement i could do for speaker.play?

Comment: Currently speaker.play before the loop is correct, the one after is useless. I think everything else looks correct. Try taking out any log messages they will slow down your thread and might cause gaps. Also you might need to try and increase your thread priority if that doesn't work. Also please mark as answer if what I am saying is correct for reputation and to help others.

Comment: I will try that and I'll get back to you. thanks for the support by the way and i will post the complete solution.

Comment: Thanks It helped, with  couple of trial and error with sampling rate and buffer size, i was able to run it.

Comment: Great to know! Good luck, getting the right buffer sizes can some times be tricky, for audio I notice smaller buffer sizes seem to get more immediate and less lag, but it is tricky.

Comment: Yes indeed, and even band with also matters, Audio streaming without SIP might be a nice idea for few nodes to communicate, but if we  have more than 10 clients SIP is crucial to maintain the connection and manage  data flow.

Comment: CodeMan> Can SIP be done client-to-client, without a SIP Server?

Comment: Yes. But than you would need to manually pass the SIP information, like an email and copy and paste it in.